# Splitting strings based on regex expression

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, split

Is there a quick way I can split a string based on a regex expression match.  Using Powershell

This string "800G1" should read "800 G1" but when the string is found it just ignores it because it is not found in an array of words that has "800" and "G1" in it.  the pattern of the string will almost always be 3 digits or a letter and 1 digit.

Is there a way I can match the string "800G1" as "800" and "G1" by splitting the string and making a match in my array.

Example Code:

```
##Incoming string from a loop
$str = "800G1"
##A pre loaded list of single words made from a list of PC models
$array = @("800"; "G1")

###The match has to determine if the incoming string can be used to build a model name.  
$match = ($array -eq $str) ##Need a regex expression to first split and find a match in the array

$match
##No Match
```

```
###I have tried this regex that may work but I cannot get it to match on the 3rd regex expression:  '^\d\d\d\G[0-9]$'
$reg =@('^G[0-9]$','^\d\d\d$', '^\d\d\d\G[0-9]$')
($tokens[1] | Select-String -pattern $reg -AllMatches).Matches.Value

$tokens[1] Returns G1
$tokens[0] Returns 800
But $str returns nothing. When it should return 800G1
```

Comment: Easier to `-join $array` and compare that to the string. You can't do `$array -eq $array2` and expect all the parts to compare in order. What else would the array contain in the full code?

Comment: Not comparing 2 arrays.   All I want to do is split the string on the fly based on character match.

Comment: If you split a string then you get an array of pieces. Comparing the pieces with an array of words *is* comparing 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
# If the string matches a certain pattern, split it in two.
[array] $tokens = 
 if ($str -match '^(\d{3})([a-z]\d)$') { $Matches.1, $Matches.2 }
 else                                  { $str }

# Test if all tokens exist as elements in the array.
# -> $true, in this case.
$allTokensContainedInArray = 
  (Compare-Object $array $tokens).SideIndicator -notcontains '=>'
```

- The regex-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) is used to test whether `$str` starts with 3 digits, followed by a letter and a single digit, and, if so, via capture groups (`(...)`) and the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), splits the string into the part with the 3 digits and the rest.
- The above uses [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to test (case-insensitively) if the array elements derived from the input string are all contained in the reference array, in any order, while allowing the reference array to contain *additional* elements.

---

If you want to limit all input strings to those matching regex pattern, before even attempting lookup in the array:

```bash
# If no pattern matches, $tokens will be $null
[array] $tokens = 
  if     ($str -match '^(\d{3})([a-z]\d)$') { $Matches.1, $Matches.2 }
  elseif ($str -match '^\d{3}$')            { $str }
  elseif ($str -match '^[a-z]\d$')          { $str }
```

Comment: The code has to determine if the incoming string in the case of the $str has the characters 800 or G1 before it tries to make a match with -eq.   How can I do that?

Comment: @IainHoward, you mean something like `$str -match '800|G1'`?

Comment: Yes,  Something like that.

Comment: So that match is true now the code can work on the string to make a match against the array.

Comment: @IainHoward, note that the above will match strings such as `'G1800'`, `'foog1bar80000'` as well. What are your exact requirements? Does `800` have to come before `G1`? Are other characters permitted too? Or only whitespace? Does `$array` contain just the components of a _single_ model, or multiple? Do the tokens have to match _in the same order_?

Comment: It will always.  And the array contains only single words like "800" "8000" "G1" G2" Etc.

Comment: The 3 digits will always precede to G1 or G2.  No Other Characters permitted.  Usually just white space between strings.  And the array only contains single one worded values.   Like so:  ProBook, 640, G8, Notebook, PC, Small, Form, Factor, G6, Dell, Storage, NX3230, R640.    All as one list.  The last 2 values have to be avoided as matches.

Comment: But it's unlikely they will crop up anyway in a string.

Comment: @IainHoward, so, aside from you having to modify `$array` to remove the last 2 elements, what about the code in this answer doesn't work as intended? I'm still confused about how the tokens should be matched against the array.

Comment: I don't have to or want to modify the array.  The only thing that needs modified is the string.  In order to build a model complete string. Like: Elitebook 800 G1 .  It's just that these strings have been manually entered and I am trying to correct them all.

Comment: @IainHoward, you said that the last 2 elements in `$array` shouldn't be matched against, so you shouldn't include them in that array to begin with - that's what I was referring to, but we can leave that aside now. Based on what you say is in `$array`, something like `$array -eq '800 G1'` will never match. How should it be matched?

Comment: `$array -eq '800'  and ` $array - 'G1'

Comment: @IainHoward, that's what my code already does, only via `Compare-Object`.

Comment: @IainHoward, if, by contrast, you need to ensure that the first token matches _earlier_ in the array than the second one - possibly requiring them to be directly next to each other - you must determine the _index_ of each token in the array.

Comment: Yes,  It does almost but how can I have the string,  800G1 be pre-determined using regex to know if the array is likely to contain it if a split were to occur.   Kinda like A.I.

Comment: I have added some code to my questions around your solution but I am struggling to get a regex match on 800G1

Comment: @IainHoward, I'm unclear on what the added code is trying to do. I've updated this answer to split `$str` by spaces, if it contains spaces, and only if there are none to  split by the position of the first non-digit. If this rule isn't sufficient and there is ultimately no rule that covers all desired splits, you'll have to iteratively create all possible ways to split the string into two pieces and compare each pair agains the array.

Comment: The original string will never have spaces.   The words in the for loop have alreadey been split by spaces.  Once each words comes in as a separate string, one of them just happened to be 1 word that is meant to be 2.  But I need a regex pattern that matches 3 digits 1 letter and a digit.  This will determine if this is a word that can be split and matched against the array.  Sorry if my question has not been explained better.

Comment: @IainHoward, please see my update.

Comment: @IainHoward, aside from missing the aspect of splitting the string, the code you added later doesn't work, because `G` is preceded by a ``\``

Comment: @IainHoward, I've added another update, based on what I think the code you added later to your question is trying to do.

Comment: I have a pattern:  `\d\d\d[G]\d`

This then can be used against this code to determine if it should be split:   
`(($str | Select-String -pattern '\d\d\d[G]\d' -AllMatches).Matches.Value -eq $str)

Comment: Then I can run the tokens through a foreach loop to build the model words.

Comment: I'll try that code later.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IainHoward, sounds good. `G` is a literal, you don't need to enclose it in `[...]`. My code assumes that any English letter is permissible, but it's obviously trivial to change it to `G`. From what I can tell, the code at the bottom of my answer now does what you want, but without `Select-String`, and with splitting based on capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of code from @mklement0 I have come up with the following solution.   This is now working as required.
I am sure that this code could probably be slimmed down though.

```
$token = $null
$str = $null
$modeld = $null
##Incoming string from loop
$str = "800G1"
##Pre-loaded array. 
$array = @("800"; "G1")

##suggested code to catch strings with a pattern of 123G1 3 digits 1 letter and digit. 
[array] $tokens = if     ($str -match '^(\d{3})([G]\d)$') 
{ $Matches.1, $Matches.2 }

#Split the captured string.  
#$tokens = $str -split '(?=\D)'

##Then build a string like '123 G1' Instead of '123G1'. 
ForEach ($token in $Tokens)
{
##Match each split string against whatever is in the array.  
$matchd = ($array -eq $token)

##If there is a match not null build it into a separate string. 
If ($matchd -ne $null)
   {
##Build the seperated strings together with a space
$modeld = $modeld + (" " + $matchd)
##Show progress....
Write-host "Model Building: $modeld"
            }
}
##Once built show Completed string. 
Write-host "Model Built: $modeld"
```

##Final output should be:

Model Built: 800 G1